# mysql how to change integer values in column from format of 20130401 to 0401

Tags: mysql

I would like to update the whole column from the format of yearmonthday to just monthday

for example a value in this column is 20130401 and I want to change it to 0401

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I would create a new column first, then populate that new field making sure that all the data is correct, and then remove the old column.

Answer (score 0):

If your column is a varchar column, you could use something like this:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET
  col = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(col, "%Y%m%d"), "%m%d")
```

or maybe just:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET col = RIGHT(col, 4)
```

**EDIT**

If you need to create a new column first and then remove the old column, you could use this:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD COLUMN col2 VARCHAR(20);

UPDATE yourtable
SET col2 = RIGHT(col, 4);

ALTER TABLE yourtable DROP COLUMN col;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96cdd/1).